# Codeigniter: Why CSS is not included when i add in controller?

Tags: php, css, codeigniter-2

This is my code where i used template to add css file.And my folder structure is
 - application
 - system
 - public
 - --css

```
$this->load->library('template');   
$tmp = new CI_Template();  
$tmp->template->add_css('/public/css/general.css', TRUE);
$this->load->view('main');
```

Comment: Did you try using a relative instead of an absolute path ?

Comment: yes i did try that option also..

Comment: have you added echo $_styles in your template view?

Comment: also where is your command to render the view?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can debug your problem:

Use this to get the class of the template `echo get_class($tmp->template)`

Go to that class, and look up the `add_css()` method - **and its parameters**. You should be able to omit the second one, but if you want to use it, you need to choose between the following 3: `link`, `import` or `embed`

After that, check what it's doing and see the resulting path.

Spoiler: The path you enter should be relative to `$config['base_path']`.

PS: You should find some more info here: http://williamsconcepts.com/ci/codeigniter/libraries/template/reference.html

Comment: Hi, I removed type='link', but still it is not including?

Comment: look at the `add_Css()` function and you will find the answer.